# List View show only rows when data exists in column

Tags: list-view

How do I set a List View to only display rows that have data in a certain column? The column's data I am testing on is alphanumeric. A logic that I assume should work is something like:

```
if (column_name.length > 0) then {
show_row;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to make that happen when editing the List View.

I have set my List View to only show rows where "Created by" "is equal to" "[Me]", and that is working great.

Comment: Why don't you update the CAML Query for List View, instead playing with XSLT ?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, where does it say he's playing with XSLT? :)

Comment: Yeah sorry guys - I'm a total Sharepoint n00b. I'm editing this List View in the standard web interface.  I don't know any other way. Thanks Arsalan for the edit. I should've used the code input tags.

Comment: @RobertLindgren List View is an XSLT List View Web Part, isn't it ?

Comment: Or just a list view app added to a page (in which you can update the view or select all the views on the list) @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: @RobertLindgren ya, maybe I just complicated the simple thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean calculated column which will check the length of the field value of particular column or whatevet correct logic is and then update boolean value.  Then create a view to filter by the boolean field.

Comment: Sounds great. How do I do that?